# Best way to track link clicks for multiple URLs in one place?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, url-parameters, sitelinks

I'm creating an ecatalog with hundreds of products. Each one has a link back to it's product page on our site. What would be the best way to track them?
My main goal is to just find how many people in general came to our site from the catalog but it doesn't show up in Google Analytics Acquisition. Would UTM parameters be the next solution or would it be too messy to have so many URLs?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "too messy" when it comes to having a lot of URLs? What do you worry would happen? Are you concerned about user confusion? Difficulty in analyzing your data in Google Analytics? Something else?